# API Authentication printify

Tags: python, php, laravel, api

I trying to make printify API auth in PHP. I have example in python, but I not getting right result. Can you explain me what I doing wrong ?

Code in python

```
 import os
    import hmac
    
    def sha256hash(request):
        hash = hmac.new(os.environ['SECRET_TOKEN'].encode('utf-8'),
                        request.data.encode('utf-8'), 
                        'sha256')
        return 'sha256=' + hash.hexdigest()
    
    
    def secure_compare(a, b):
        return hmac.compare_digest(a, b)
    
    
    print('%r' % secure_compare(request.headers['x-pfy-signature'],
                                sha256hash(request)))
```

This is my current php code:

```
public function onCreated(Request $request) {
        $secured_token = $request->header('X-Pfy-Signature');
        if(!$this->checkAuth(utf8_encode($request), $secured_token)){
            $secured_token = "test";
        }
    }
  
    protected function checkAuth($data, $hashFromPrintify) {
        $private_key = utf8_encode(config('printifywebhook.token'));
        $hash = hash_hmac( "sha256" , $data , $private_key);
        $hash = "sha256=".md5($hash);
        if($hash == $hashFromPrintify) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Where I made mistake ?

Comment: `$hash = "sha256=".md5($hash);` Why is `md5()` here? Don't you just want the output of the HMAC?

Comment: I think that .hexdigest() function in Python mean md5(). Or I am not right ?

Comment: I would imagine that hexdigest means output this hash object in hex. Check the docs.

Comment: What does `utf8_encode` do? Have you read the documentation to ensure it does what you think it does?

Comment: On every API request I getting different signature. This is my first time when I trying create HMAC auth.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $signature = $request->header('X-Pfy-Signature');
    $payload = $request->getContent();
    $secret = config('printifywebhook.token');
    $result = $this->hash_is_valid($secret, $payload, $signature);
    if(!$result) {
        return response()->json(['ACCESS TOKEN NOT VALID']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
protected function compute_hash($secret, $payload)
{
    $hexHash = hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($payload), utf8_encode($secret));
    return $hexHash;
}

protected function hash_is_valid($secret, $payload, $verify)
{
    $computed_hash = "sha256=".$this->compute_hash($secret, $payload);
    return hash_equals($verify,$computed_hash);
}
```